# A = B when Ax = Bx for some nonzero n-vector x

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $m$ x $n$ matrices.

How do I determine whether $A = B$ always holds or only sometimes when:

$Ax = Bx$ for some nonzero $n$-vector $x$.

I know that $A = B$ holds always iff $Ax = Bx$ for all n-vectors $x$, however I am unsure about when $Ax = Bx$ for some nonzero n-vector $x$

Comment: This is not true in general. It shouldn't be too hard to find a counterexample (tip: perhaps try choosing $x$ first, and then pick $A,B$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A$ be the matrix of all zeros. Can you find a matrix $B\neq A$ and a vector $v$ such that $Av=Bv$?

Comment: If A is a vector of all zeros, then doesn't that mean that B must also be 0?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, not a vector. There are nonzero vectors that get mapped to the zero vector by a matrix that is not the zero matrix, however.

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax_i=Bx_i$ where $(x_i)$ generates $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $Ax=Bx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus $A=B$.

Comment: That also includes zero vectors, what about if x is a non-zero n vector

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you have $Ax_i=Bx_i$ for some vectors $x_i$ (that are non-zero vectors) such that $(x_i)$ linearly generates $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $A=B$, what is the problem here ?

Comment: I was supposed to find a counterexample to show that it doesn't always hold. Which I let A = (1,0,0,0), B = (2,0,0,0), x = (0,y)

Comment: Ok, nevermind .